# Power BI: Modify table via custom function

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, can a table be modified via an M function?

I have tried manipulating the table via Table.DeleteRows, Table.InsertRows etc. but the underlying table is not modified.

My idea:

**Table**

- Contains OAuth2 authentication details

**Function**

- Validates the current authentication details
- If authentication details have expired, new authentication details are retrieved via an API call
- New authentication details should then be stored in the Table

The above setup is designed to allow other API requests to use the same authentication details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking if Power BI can modify the source data (e.g. a SQL database table), then no, it is **not** designed to do that. It's possible to do so indirectly by calling stored procedures that modify the source tables, but the Power BI query editor is intended to be read-only with respect to the original source.